# Calculate upper bound for put option prices?

Tags: options, derivatives

I need to know historical option prices for backtesting. The problem is I don't have such historical data.

Is there a way to calculate the upper bound for **out of money (American) put option** selling price?

I'm testing strategy that going to buy put options as an insurance, so the upper bound should model the worst possible price (the highest possible buy price for me).

Comment: If you look at European options, the put's price is at most worth $Ke^{-rT}$, an American put at most $K$, where $K$ is the strike (exercise) price. This result is independent of the monyness of the option and independent of any model assumption of the stock price dynamics. Those no arbitrage boundaries may however be too large for your purposes.

Comment: @KeSchn I'm looking for American options, but $K$ as an upper bound is too high :)

Comment: This paper would be of interest (if you have not seen it!): https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/fut.21961 (Robust upper bounds for American put options, by Ye Du, Shan Xue, and Yanchu Liu)